# WiX - passing checkbox values from Burn UI to MSI

Tags: checkbox, wix, burn

I have custom UI in Burn with a checkbox "Install Desktop icon". And I have the same thing in my MSI (also created with WiX) that I'm replacing with Burn. The problem is that Burn seems to set checkbox values to `0` or `1` (via `MsiProperty`) whereas my MSI expects `NULL` or `NOT NULL`. If you try to send through the checkbox value from Burn it will always be evaluated as NOT NULL by the MSI. I have found that I can edit my WiX projects and change:

```
<Condition>DESKTOP_ICONS</Condition>
```

to:

```
<Condition>DESKTOP_ICONS = 1</Condition>
```

and this will solve the problem. But is there any way of getting Burn to pass NULL or NOT NULL to the MSI based on the value of a checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burn will treat "true" and "checked" as "1" and "0" for false. However, you could create a custom action in your MSI that would convert the numeric property into "NULL".  It'd look something like:

```
<SetProperty Id="NULL" Value="1" After="AppSearch">DESKTOP_ICONS = 1</SetProperty>
```

Now the `Property` named "NULL" (which is a pretty funny name for a property, IMHO) will be defined if `DESKTOP_ICONS` property was set to "1".

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I can see how editing the MSI would allow a Burn checkbox value to flow through to the MSI but I wanted to avoid having to edit the MSI - it looks like this is not possible.

Another way of looking at this is if you had a logical property that you wanted to set via the command line it would be: 

`msiexec /i my.msi MYVAR=1`

and then the reverse, i.e. to have `MYVAR` undefined, it would be:

`msiexec /i my.msi MYVAR=""` 

You can achieve the first with Burn but not the second as far as I can see - not if you want to control it with a checkbox in Burn's UI.